# composer and Lightning

Tags: 8, composer

I have composer.jon to require

```
"acquia/lightning": "2.1.3",
```

This installs Drupal core 8.3.3. Can I change this to Drupal core 8.3.2 or does Lightning force you to use the Drupal version its packaged with?

I updated this post after fixing the problem. I changed the composer.json file and specified what drupal core version to use like this.

```
    "acquia/lightning": "2.1.3",
    "drupal/core": "8.3.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've largely answered your own question. But to confirm, Lightning generally does not pin to a specific version of core in it's composer.json file. The [current constraint](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/blob/21fdce7ac744ef52b581242cd7aea2e9c9eab2a4/composer.json#L128) is `~8.3.1` (note the tilde) which means the current release of Lightning should work with core 8.3.1 to 8.3.9(repeating) but not 8.4.0.

Core is the exception to the rule. Lightning normally pins to specific versions of dependencies if they are patched (see [Lightning's dependency constraint logic](http://lightning.acquia.com/blog/dependency-version-contraints)). But since core follows SemVer, has predictable releases, and Lightning releases every time core does, Lightning doesn't pin core - even when it is patched (which is [pretty much always](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/blob/8.x-2.x/composer.json#L79)).

Lightning increments the second digit of its release numbers (the minor release) when Drupal makes a minor release. In the current release of Lightning (2.1.4) [the `one` relates to the `three` in the current release of core](https://github.com/acquia/lightning/blob/8.x-2.x/VERSIONS.md) (8.3.3). So Lightning 2.1.x should run on any core 8.3.x. That's why Lightning uses the tilde (~) modifier and three digits when specifying Drupal core constraints.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that lightning had its own composer.json file until you said that. I see it now in: docroot/profiles/contrib/lightning/. And I see the tilde for the Drupal core version. If the composer.json is higher up in the project folder does it override lower composer.json files? The main composer file is in the root folder of the project. And I specifically entered drupal/core": "8.3.2.

Comment: Higher up in the folder hierarchy does not make a difference. Nor does the mere existence of a composer.json file actually do anything. When you require a dependency from your root composer.json file (as you have done for Lightning), the dependencies dependency's are then negotiated. Higher specificity will "win" as long as it doesn't conflict with another dependency's constraints.